# How to add my data to the starting of the json object using python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have on json file with the following code

```
"destinations": [
     {
        "/abc/def": {

  "proxy_pass":"https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args",
            "host": "{{application_destination}}",

            }
        }
]
```

I have to add the url of proxy_pass to some variable and then add that variable to 
the proxy_pass using python code

```
if "proxy_pass" in location_details:
            proxy_pass = location_details[proxy_pass]
            location_details["set"] = "$backend " + proxy_pass
            location_details["proxy_pass"] = "$backend"
```

But the output I am getting is after proxy_pass,  set value is printing
So how to add the set value to the starting of the json object using python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python `dict` objects are unordered until [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)

You can use [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


location_details = OrderedDict({
    "proxy_pass": "https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args",
    "host": "{{application_destination}}",
})

if "proxy_pass" in location_details:
    proxy_pass = location_details.pop('proxy_pass')
    location_details["set"] = "$backend " + proxy_pass
    location_details["proxy_pass"] = "$backend"

print(json.dumps(location_details, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "host": "{{application_destination}}", 
    "set": "$backend https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args", 
    "proxy_pass": "$backend"
}
```

---

**EDIT**

To get the required order of

1. `set`
2. `proxy_pass`
3. `host`

you can use [`OrderedDict.move_to_end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) move the `host` key to the end of the `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


location_details = OrderedDict({
    "proxy_pass": "https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args",
    "host": "{{application_destination}}",
})

if "proxy_pass" in location_details:
    proxy_pass = location_details.pop('proxy_pass')
    location_details["set"] = "$backend " + proxy_pass
    location_details["proxy_pass"] = "$backend"
    location_details.move_to_end('host')

print(json.dumps(location_details, indent=4))
```

**Output**

```
{
    "set": "$backend https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args",
    "proxy_pass": "$backend",
    "host": "{{application_destination}}"
}
```

**Note**

You can also use `location_details.move_to_end(key, last=False)` to move `key` to the beginning of the dictionary

Comment: Thanks for your information.But proxy_pass should not move to end set value should come first and then proxy_pass .                                                                       
  {
   
    "set": "$backend https://{{application_destination}}/abc/service$is_args$args", 
    "proxy_pass": "$backend"                                                                                
     "host": "{{application_destination}}", 
}                                                                                                                               
  This output I am looking for